# HTML print </> instead of &lt;/&gt;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formatting

I set text in a html Element with JQuery like that

```
$('#xmlTextArea').text(prepareXML(response))
```

I want to replace all `<` and `>` with `&gt;` and `&lt;` as I use a prettify Lib, that doesn't recognize the entities. I replace it like that:

```
function prepareXML(req){
    str = req.replace(/</g,"&lt;")
    str = str.replace(/>/g,"&gt;")
    console.log(str)
    return str
}
```

But now it prints the String `&gt;` instead of the sign `>`. So to summarize I want the output to look the same, but beeing `&gt;` under the hood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method internally do the same, so there is no need to call the `prepareXML` method.

```
$('#xmlTextArea').text(response)
```

---

Or use [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead.

```
$('#xmlTextArea').html(prepareXML(response))
```